# Angular - Prevent reload of controller if already running

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I made an Angular application with several anchors. Every anchor loads an Angular controller with its template, what to load is defined by the $routeProvider, here is the code:

```
ApioApplication.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/home',{
    templateUrl : 'systemApps/home/app.home.html',
      controller : 'ApioHomeController',
      reloadOnSearch: false
    }).when('/home/:application',{
      templateUrl : 'systemApps/home/app.home.html',
      controller : 'ApioHomeController',
      reloadOnSearch: false
    }).when('/wall',{
      templateUrl : 'systemApps/wall/app.wall.html',
      controller : 'ApioWallController',
      reloadOnSearch: false
    }).when('/events',{
      templateUrl : 'systemApps/events/app.events.html',
      controller : 'ApioEventsController',
      reloadOnSearch: false
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

Apparently there's nothing strange but I've seen that every time I click on an anchor Angular reloads the controller, even if it was load before.
So here is my question: is there a way with $routeProvider, or some other Angular feature, to check if a controller is already running in order to prevent its reload?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a route is matched, that controller instance would run - it doesn't matter if another route has the same controller. You could definitely do some wonky to prevent the same controller from running, but in your case it is entirely unnecessary, since you could just have a single route and an optional parameter `application`:

```
.when('/home/:application?', {...})
```

And then in the controller you could do:

```
.controller("ApioHomeController", function($routeParams){
   if ($routeParams.application){
     //...
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I'd like (if possible) to use more than one controller. I'd like my application to be as modular as possible.

Comment: How's that more modular by duplicating routes?

Comment: Ok, but in that case I have to do only one controller from all routes. Instead I want to do one controller per route

Comment: @user2902455, not for *all*, but just for the one with a parameter - there is no reason to duplicate the route in that case